# Top 20 Count of SKUs per Store

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression, sql-server-2017

I am trying to create a query that pulls down the top 20 out of stock SKUs per store. Here is what I have so far:

```
;with top20OOS as
(select wi.SKU 
, count(wi.SKU) OOSCount
, wi.ProductId
, wi.PseudoStoreId
from WaveItem wi (nolock)
where wi.isOutOfStock = 1
and DateAdded between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-31'
group by wi.SKU, p.ProductName, wi.ProductId, bo.brandname, p.size, mo.name, 
wi.PseudoStoreId
)

select oos.SKU
, oos.ProductName
, oos.OOSCount
, s.StoreName
, s.StoreID from top20OOS oos
join WaveItem wi (nolock) on  wi.ProductId = oos.ProductId
    and wi.PseudoStoreId = oos.PseudoStoreId
join tblStore s (nolock) on s.PseudoStoreID = wi.PseudoStoreId
where s.StoreID in (1094,1088)
and DateAdded between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-31'
group by oos.SKU, oos.ProductName, s.StoreName, s.StoreID, oos.OOSCount
order by s.StoreName asc, OOSCount desc
```

This just pulls all of the out of stock SKUs for stores 1094 and 1088, and I need to limit it to the top 20 per store. I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: What is your question and can you post the error if there is one?

Comment: You'll need to add a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY x,y,z) AS rn. Then WHERE rn <= 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit verbose because I can't remember if ROW_NUMBER() plays well with Group By in the same query so I erred on the side of caution and broke it apart into separate subqueries.

```
;with top20OOS as
(select wi.SKU 
, count(wi.SKU) OOSCount
, wi.ProductId
, wi.PseudoStoreId
from WaveItem wi (nolock)
where wi.isOutOfStock = 1
and DateAdded between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-31'
group by wi.SKU, p.ProductName, wi.ProductId, bo.brandname, p.size, mo.name, 
wi.PseudoStoreId
)

SELECT sku,
       productName,
       OOSCount,
       StoreName,
       StoreID     
  FROM (SELECT sku,
               productName,
               OOSCount,
               StoreName,
               StoreID,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY StoreID 
                       ORDER BY OOSCount
                 ) AS rn
          FROM (select oos.SKU
                , oos.ProductName
                , oos.OOSCount
                , s.StoreName
                , s.StoreID from top20OOS oos
                join WaveItem wi (nolock) on  wi.ProductId = oos.ProductId
                    and wi.PseudoStoreId = oos.PseudoStoreId
                join tblStore s (nolock) on s.PseudoStoreID = wi.PseudoStoreId
                where s.StoreID in (1094,1088)
                and DateAdded between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-31'
                group by oos.SKU, oos.ProductName, s.StoreName, s.StoreID, oos.OOSCount
               ) TMP
       ) TMP2
 WHERE rn <= 20;
```

Comment: Great! If it did the trick for you please accept the answer to save others time.